# Kendo ui if else angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, if-statement, kendo-grid

How can I make a condition in Kendo UI grid using angularjs which will check an integer from the table and in relation with this (if 1 then some class, if 2 then some other class..) apply the class on the cell where is the integer located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created a fiddle for the same,check if this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sowjanya51/krszen9a/

I have used if-else,you can use switch too for conditional.

```
 if(this.innerText=='1')
```

Comment: if it helped you and is the solution you are looking for then please mark it as answer so it will be helpful for others :-) Thanks !!!

Comment: I wanted, but I don`t have reputation for voting yet :( sorry